# Converting HMAC-SHA1 from node.js to Java

Tags: java, node.js, cryptography, hmac, hmacsha1

I have been tasked with converting some existing piece of node.js code to Java. I think I'm well on my way, but I'm kind of stuck right now. The output of the methods do not seem to match.

What I'm doing is creating a SHA-1 signature based on a query string. This query string contains some query-related data (not relevant for this question) and an API key.

**Important**

- The `api_secret` string in node.js is equivalent to `Config.API_SECRET` in Java.
- Example query string (these are equal in the node.js and Java program):
  `/events?festival=imaginate&pretty=1&size=100&from=0&key=SOME_KEY`

**Actual code**

The SHA-1 hmac is initialized as follows in nodejs:

```
const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', api_secret);
```

The SHA-1 mac is initialized as follows in Java:

```
final SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(Config.API_SECRET.getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA1");
final Mac hmac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
hmac.init(secretKeySpec);
```

Next, the node.js program updates the hmac as such (`query` parameter is as listed above):

```
hmac.update(query, 'ascii');
```

Which I replicated in Java like this (`query` parameter is equal to the node.js `query` parameter):

```
hmac.update(query.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
```

Finally, the byte string is converted to a SHA-1 hash as such in the node.js program:

```
const signature = hmac.digest('hex');
```

I couldn't find an exact translation to Java, but this was my attempt, which I think does about the same thing:

*Byte array to hex function*

```
public static String byteArrayToHex(byte[] a) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(a.length * 2);
    for(byte b: a)
        sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

*Actual usage*

```
byte[] result = hmac.doFinal();
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
String sha1Hash = byteArrayToHex(md.digest(result));
```

However, this is where I get confused. The node.js program returns this hash:
`18cf4fce7bd6163c64d3b2ea8d935b0f16720fe3`

But my Java program gives this hash as output:
`f65f8738cce89134dc73709e3353d94c83ccf1fb`

I can't figure out where I went wrong and I really hope someone could shed a light on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

Turns out I was doing one unnecessary step.

This line:

```
byte[] result = mac.doFinal();
```

Already contained the signature hash. I needed to convert that byte array to a hex string, not the digest of that byte array.

So the working code was simply:

```
byte[] result = mac.doFinal();
return byteArrayToHex(result);
```